# Rendering PDF graphics without aliasing

Tags: graphics, pdf, aliasing

I am using MATLAB to generate .eps vector graphics, editing them in Adobe Illustrator, and then saving them as a PDF.

When I view the image through Adobe Acrobat, it is covered with cross-hatched white lines (an aliasing problem).  These can be hidden, however, by de-selecting `Edit->Preferences...->Page Display->Rendering->Smooth line art`.

However, when I import the PDF into my LaTeX document, the aliasing again appears in the compiled version.  Is there a way to tell LaTeX the same thing that I told Adobe Acrobat (that is, do not render the pdf with "smooth line art")?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, LaTeX does not (or should not) smooth, nor alter in other way the imported pdf figure. Perhaps it is an issue of the viewer you use to view the pdflatex result. Try using the same viewer (Adobe Acrobat) you used to view the image.

Answer (score 1):

**Possible cause:** The problem is likely to be a "fill pattern" where areas are filled with a repeating tile in the original .eps file.  The smoothing done by most (all?) pdf viewers doesn't like trying to join the edges of two "smoothed" tiles - the feathered blur at the edges of two adjacent tiles never matches perfectly.

**Workaround:** Unless you really want a patterned fill, replace the fill with a uniform fill, either at Matlab end or in the Illustrator tweaking.  As in JLDiaz's answer, this can't be done by LaTeX.  Whether such manual work is worth doing in this case is not clear from the question.